# On the equation of a line in $2$D.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I've just learned the 'Vector' equation of a line, which is :
$$\vec{X}=\vec{P}+t\vec{u}$$
Where the vector $u$ is parallel to the vector $X$ and $t$ is a real number. So I've tried to find the equation of a straight line $ax+by=c$, This is my attempt:

Let $\vec{X}=\langle x,y\rangle$, $\vec{P}=\langle p,q \rangle$ and $\vec{u}=\langle a,b\rangle$, so:
$$\langle x,y\rangle=\langle p,q \rangle+t\langle a,b\rangle$$
$$\langle x,y\rangle=\langle p+ta,q+tb \rangle \implies$$
$$\cases{x=p+ta \\y=q+tb}$$

To get an equation without $t$ we should eliminate it so I will multiply both sides of the second equation by $-a/b$ and the two equations:
$$x-\frac{a}{b}y=p-\frac{a}{b}q$$
but this equation doesn't look like $ax+by=c$, if I know the vector equation of a line, How can I find this equation?

Comment: Think of it like this: $\vec{u}$ is the direction of the line (a vector along the line itself) and $\vec{P}$ is a particular point through which the line passes. To obtain the equation of a line $ax+by=c$ you need the direction (think of a vector connecting two points along the line) and a specific point lying on the line. Note that there many possible equivalent vector line equations for the same line, just as there are many equivalent equations for the line $ax + by = c$.

Comment: well, to get a vector connecting $2$ points along that line, should I consider the point $P$ and $P+tu$ so that the vector connecting them is $tu$ ??? @TannySieben

Comment: So you want a direction vector $ \vec{u}$ along the line. There are many possible ways to obtain this: one of them would be to just guess two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ on the line. Another way would be to use the fact that the direction vector needs only to be parallel to the line, so you can translate it so that is passes through the origin; In that case, you can take the vector connecting $(0,0)$ and $(1,-\frac{a}{b})$, where $-\frac{a}{b}$ is the slope of the line, which is indeed parallel to $ax + by = c$ (given $a \neq 0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ax + by = c$ means $y = \frac{c - ax}{b} = \frac{c}{b} -\frac{a}{b}x$. So points on the line are of the form $$\left(x, \frac{c}{b} -\frac{a}{b}x\right) = \left(0, \frac{c}{b}\right) + \left(1, -\frac{a}{b}\right)x,\hspace{20pt} x \in \mathbb{R}.$$